# How do i upload image from link to my server?

Tags: php, facebook-php-sdk

I have facebook login and signup on my site. I have looked here and there and i am trying to upload image from link.

suppose this is link of image as i wanted to upload image from facebook

`http://graph.facebook.com/shaverm/picture?type=large`

this will change into

`http://m.ak.fbcdn.net/profile.ak/hprofile-ak-ash4/372183_100002526091955_998385602_n.jpg`

Now i want it to upload on my site

this image:

`http://m.ak.fbcdn.net/profile.ak/hprofile-ak-ash4/372183_100002526091955_998385602_n.jpg`

I have found this code here on stackoverflow but i am not sure how this will work out i am trying this from last 2 hours and trying to figure it out but not able to do so i posted here.

```
$image = @ImageCreateFromString(@file_get_contents($imageURL));

if (is_resource($image) === true){
    // image is valid, do your magic here
}else{
    // not a valid image, show error
}
```

This are my code from which i upload picture right now on my site.

```
if ($_FILES) {
    $name = $_FILES['filename']['name'];
    $size = $_FILES["filename"]["size"];
    switch ($_FILES['filename']['type']) {
        case 'image/jpeg':
            $ext = 'jpg';
            break;           
        default:
            $ext = '';
            break;
}
if ($ext) {
    if ($size > 800000) {
        $imagefalse = '<span id="font">Image is bigger in size sorry!<br / ></span>';
    } else {
        $path = $imagelink; // old path of image
        unlink($path); // remove old file if any
        $timestamp = time();
        $n = "image/user/$id.$timestamp.$ext";
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'], $n);
        $setnewimage = mysql_query("UPDATE users SET image='$n' WHERE id='$id'");
    }
} else
    $imagefalse = '<span id="font">File is not an accepted image file<br / ></span>';
}
```

Comment: `if (is_resource($image) === true){ file_put_contents('url/to/new/file/on/sever.jpg', $image) }`

Answer (score 1):

You probably need [curl](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php); it is a HTTP (& FTP) client library.

Comment: can i have little idea? of which library i need ?

Comment: @MeAndMySelf He linked it. :-|

Comment: I have seen it all but nothing about image on that page.

Comment: There is nothing specific to images in your question. You want to *upload* and that requires making an HTTP request. Uploading text, HTML pages, CSS files, or images is still uploading.